# Disable email notification for WooCommerce manual/edit orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, email-notifications

WooCommerce expertise needed

I need to disable email notifications for orders that I create manually, I have to use the processing status, I can't create a custom status because of a custom hook for the processing order status.

Ideally a checkbox in the manual order page that could be ticked and when it is ticked it will disable email from sending to the customer at every status. (processing - completed).

Reason is that ebay orders have to be entered into the backend orders for database reasons and we dont want emails resent to the customer that have already been sent via ebay.

I am guessing that this hook will need to be called:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
```

And this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to remove them from the admin and continue to have new order emails sent when customers purchase things on the frontend, wrap the action removals in some logic to check for that case.  I have included all of the relevant emails from this WooCom example (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/), removing the ones that either are not generated by creating/editing orders in the admin or already have an option to send or not send (notes).

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );

function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {

        // New order emails
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

        // Processing order emails
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

        // Completed order emails
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [the function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/). In functions.php or a custom plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );

function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {

remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) ); // cancels automatic email of order complete status update.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) ); // cancels automatic email of new order placed (when defined to procession status)
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) ); // cancels automatic email of status update to processing.
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to provide a summary here too in case the link breaks in future.