# Disable Email Notifications to Customers Only When Orders are Manually Entered by Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

We have about 200 orders that we would like to add manually in the back end of WooCommerce, when logged in as an admin. We do not want to send an automatic email to the Customer when the order has been entered.

I have read a very similar post on the forum, that basically asks the same question, but the answers explain how to prevent sending emails to the admin and do not explain how to inhibit sending emails to the Customer.

That post is here: [Disable email notification for WooCommerce manual/edit orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485013/disable-email-notification-for-woocommerce-manual-edit-orders)

I have tried a method prescribed by WooCommerce, but it prevents ALL email from being sent

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'unhook_those_pesky_emails' );

function unhook_those_pesky_emails( $email_class ) {

/**
* Hooks for sending emails during store events
**/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'low_stock' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock_notification', array( $email_class, 'no_stock' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder_notification', array( $email_class, 'backorder' ) );

// New order emails
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_New_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

// Processing order emails
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

// Completed order emails
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );

// Note emails
remove_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Note'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code in functions.php

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

// enter your codes
remove_action( 'woocommerce_new_customer_note_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Note'], 'trigger' ) );


}
```